# Weka Prediction with Java

Tags: java, weka

I need to predict the end sem marks using regression in Java. This is what I have so far

```
public class LR{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader datafile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\dataset.arff"));
        Instances data = new Instances(datafile);

        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);    //setting class attribute
        datafile.close();

        LinearRegression lr = new LinearRegression();  //build model
        int folds=10;

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data);
        eval.crossValidateModel(lr, data, folds, new Random(1));
        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString()); 

        //save the model
        weka.core.SerializationHelper.write("C:\\lr.model", lr);

        //load the model
        Classifier cls = (Classifier)weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("C:\\lr.model");

    }
}
```

How can I use the loaded model to predict the marks of students which are in another file: `"testfile"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the other file as Weka instances, iterate over each instance and call `cls.classifyInstance`.

See [This example](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code#toc19)

Comment: I am getting an error for the line double clsLabel = cls.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i)); i can't find the error

Comment: @user5538704 use a debugger